# From Euler angles to Rotation matrix Staubli

Tags: robotic-arm, forward-kinematics, industrial-robot, rotation, transforms

I want to know the transformation matrix between End effector and Robot base (FK). Staubli gives me x,y,z and Rx,Ry,Rz. Those three Rotations are Euler angles? How could I transform those Euler angles to Rotation matrix? What convention of Euler does Staubli use? It should be R = Rz(φ)Ry(θ)Rx(ψ)?

Comment: I think those Rx, Ry & Rz angles are basic rotations.  The rotation around the x axis, y axis & z axis respectively. Staubli is just a textile company, correct?  Why would they use anything but common Rotation Matrix math?

Comment: Staubli is also a robot manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

Consider using elemental rotation matrices as defined on [this wikipedia.org page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

[image: elemental rotation matrices from wikipedia]

... then substituting the angle into the trigonometric functions in the matrix and finally cross multiplying the X, Y & Z matrix with the rotation matrix. For example to rotate a vector [1, 0, 0] 90 degrees about the Z axis perform the following calculations:

[image]